# Move Avatar using react vr

Tags: aframe, webvr, react-360

Am new to react vr world , i learned basics of react vr from some of the sites .And i tired some sample projects too . I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/coding-artist/learn-react-vr-chapter-1-hello-virtual-world-202241c0cb63)

Although i searched from many sites i dont know how to move a avatar inside `pano` or any other vr `components` . Can any one tell/help/guide to move avatar inside React vr pano . or suggest me some tutorial which explains moving of avatar inside pano .

Comment: What do you mean by 'avatar', some 2D graphic?

Comment: Yes , 3d objects . .a ball , a cube . .etc . .whatever. .. the thing is i want to move that object inside <a-scene></a-scene>

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want just add child components so for example to nest `Model` inside `Pano`:

```
<Pano>
 <Model></Model>
</Pano>
```

like in HTML. You can read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/react-vroverview.html) about JSX in ReactVR.

Comment: i did that already bro , the thing is i dont know how to move that Model , For example lets say  i have car model i want to drive the car inside that pano . . is it possible ?  Do you have any refernce link for that  ? if so please suggest me .. .  thanks for your valuable time :)

Comment: Oh so I think something like this is not possible in React VR, at least not straightforward. As far as I know, 'Your' position is always centered. However, I was experimenting with stuff like that and I made something similar by moving everything around me, for example after clicking 'W' all objects positions changed + 0.1 but it was quite simple, you couldn't turn around etc. Also, I'm not sure how efficient it will be with more objects, it's framework for 3D/VR websites not 3D games engine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Model 
  style={{
          transform: [{translate: [this.state.x,this.state.y,this.state.x]}]
        }}

source source={{ obj: asset("earth.obj"), mtl: asset("earth.mtl") }}
lit={true}
/>
```

//increase the value of the x,y,z it will look like it is running
//or use the setTimeout function to update the value of x,y,z